# backbone general controller structure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to backbone and js. I have a general question regarding code structure. I'm currently building a webpage with a layout view and two regions. The left region is populated and shown on pageload. The right region is only shown and populated on a click in the left region. My controller looks like the following:

```
mainView.leftRegion.show(treeview); 
...
treeItemView.on("childview:item:click", function(childview, item){
    // Fetch collection of subitems from datasource
    var fetchingSubitems = App.request("subitems:entity", item.get("id"));

    ...

    // when done update item model with fetched collection
    item.set({subitems : subitems});

    var subitemsView = new app.subitemsList({
            model : item
    });

    mainView.rightRegion.show(subitemsView);
}
```

My issue is that I want to show the right view outside of the click event and then update it, when the item model is being updated. But how should I structure it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a general state Backbone model which contains subItems :

```
var State =  Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults : {
        subItems: []
    }
```

});

send this model to the left and the right views on initialize :

```
state = new State();
   var treeView = new TreeView({state:state});
   var subitemsView = new app.subitemsList({state:state});
   mainView.leftRegion.show(treeview);
   mainView.rightRegion.show(subitemsView);
```

when you click on item you modify the state model :

```
treeItemView.on("childview:item:click", function(childview, item){
// Fetch collection of subitems from datasource
    var fetchingSubitems = App.request("subitems:entity", item.get("id"));

    ...

    // when done update state model
    state.set("subItems",fetchingSubItems);



}
```

the right view must listen to change on subItems on state model :

```
this.listenTo(state, "change:subitems", this.changeCollectionAndRender);
```

the method "changeCollectionAndRender" must get the list of subItems from state model , update its collection and rerender :

```
changeCollectionAndRender:function(){

this.collection = this.state.get("subItems");
this.render();
}
```